# What's the best way to implement update deeply nested JSON structure with Spring Data REST?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-data-rest

I have many related resources with exported repositories on the backend (Spring Data REST).
My client loads "root" resource with GET and then lazy-loads related resources through "_links" properties.
Then client can modify some resources in the loaded graph.

I want to implement service, which will take json with all lazy-loaded resources and update modified resources with version-checking (optimistic) at once.

What's the best way to implement this?
Is this approach a bad practice?

Comment: Sounds as a good place for https://www.graphql.com/

Comment: Sounds like a good approach, but would be interesting to see how you implement it. With certain missing configuration, can send JVM for a toss, make sure you implement singleton design-pattern for utility stuff

Comment: How about, "don't do that"? JSON is a representation of a data structure, not the data structure itself. Use a proper abstraction and encapsulation. Convert to and from JSON only on I/O.

Comment: @Raedwald, sorry, but I didn't understand your suggestion. As I see, client always transfer to server some "representation" of a data structure. Then server should convert and persist it. Why client can't transfer to server nested json as representation of modified data?

Comment: @StanislavL, can you copy your comment to the Answer? I think it should be accepted answer for my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds as a good place for [graphql.com](https://www.graphql.com/)

It allows to get all of the data you need, in one request. You can define API and call queries requesting only necessary part of data.

It supports customized updates as well.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't completely understand what do you mean but if you want to load nested resources 'eagerly' in SDR, you can turn off exporting of related 'nested' repos (or even completely remove them). For example:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
   //...
   @OneToMany(cascaded = ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   private Set<Child> children;
}

@Entity
public class Child {
   //...
}

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface ParentRepo extends JpaRepository<Parent, Long> {}

@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)
public interface ChildRepo extends JpaRepository<Child, Long> {}
```

Also you can add `cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true` parameters to `OneToMany` annotation.

Then all your child objects will be managed by Parent object, and the common payload will be looks like this:

```
{
   "name": "parent1",
   "children": [
      {
         "name": "child1"
      },

      {
         "name": "child2"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think, that I need mixed behavior: client loads resources lazily, but updates them with one request.
Can I make resources "exported=true" on write and "exported=false" on read?

Comment: Don't forget to accept/upvote answers that helped you... ;)

Comment: I accept your answer in other question, but this question is still unclear for me. I want to have "exported" resources (clients lazy load them), but I need something like "transaction" to "commit" modified resources together.

Comment: @Aleksandr Just create the payload according to my example and POST it. All these objects will be persisted together in one transaction. (Don't forget to set `cascade = ALL`...)

Comment: I already did similar config (with @RestResource(exported = false)). But the problem is that with this approach I always get all nested objects. Can I get resources separately, but write them with one request?